# Unity 3D: How to make a Camera blend to a color and back?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

I'm teleporting my player with my camera, so I want to have my Camera go dark for a second and then back to normal. How would I achieve this?

I'm not using Cinemachine ATM but think of doing so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should make two animations with unity animation window to a UI panel

1. create new UI> panel
   2.Give it a color Black with alpha 0
2. animate the color from black alpha 0 to black with alpha 255 or 1 btw you should animate opacity from 0 to max and name it "Fade in"
3. make another animation form max alpha to transparent call it "Fade out"

now you have two animation when you need  your camera go dark animate use Fade in